# Laravel 5.2 Implicit Route Model Binding - No query results for model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am getting the following error when I am trying to access a route containing 2 wildcards using implicit route model binding:

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 102: 
No query results for model [App\Country].

ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 304: 
No query results for model [App\Country].
```

The route I am trying to access is to a page with a form to edit a country that relates to a region (which is in a route group with 'prefix' => 'destination-editor' which in turn is in an 'admin' route group):

```
Route::get('/region/{region}/editcountry/{country}', 'CountryController@edit');
```

which should match the URL: laravel.local.com/admin/destination-editor/region/1/editcountry/1

Here is my edit method of the `CountryController` which takes the region and the country:

```
public function edit(Region $region, Country $country)
{
    return view('admin.destinationeditor.country.edit', compact('region', 'country'));
}
```

The view that is loaded is

```
@extends('templates.admin.master')

@section('content')
    <h1 class="noTopMargin">Edit country: {{$country->name}}</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="{{route('editCountry', [$region->id, $country->id])}}">

        @include('admin.destinationeditor.partials.countryform', ['submitButtonText' => 'Edit country'])

    </form>
@endsection
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error as I have both a region and country in my DB with an ID of 1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Is your model in `App/`? If so, try running `composer dumpautoload`. If not, Try using the full namespace instead.

Comment: Yes all my models are in App/. I have tried using the full namespace and running `composer dumpautoload` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you check the following file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`? It must have something like `'App\\Country' => $baseDir . '/app/Country.php'`. If not, add `"psr-4": {"App\\": "app/" }` into `autoload` in `composer.json` and rerun `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: have you tried seeing if model binding works with just `region/{region}` instead of including them both at first?

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your `country` table.

Comment: Model binding does work if I use just `region/{region}`, so narrowing things down, it must be an issue I have with the country. The schema for my country table is

Comment: `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('country', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('uri')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('enabled');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`